# Log-In to StackOverflow

Tags: support, login, openid

I am very confused by the Login process for this site and for StackOverflow.
I was told that my ID is an url (not an email address) but I have no idea what it is.

That said, I think you have placed a cookie on my machine after I just reset my password because a new ("Login") button appeared and when I clicked it, I was in without even entering a password.

Comment: You were most likely still logged into your OpenID provider. And what would your provider be?

Comment: How did you sign up for Stack Overflow in the first place?